# Convert string value into float value

Tags: iphone, nsmutablearray, nsarray

How do I convert a string to a float in Objective-C?

I am trying to add a couple of strings I am getting back from XML:

```
float subTotal = [[[[pintsary objectAtIndex:i]objectForKey:@"Price"] floatValue];

NSLog(@"%@",subTotal));
```

but it gives error

Comment: Is this kind of a challenge for the SO community? Or why are you whitholding the error message and its context (compile-time, run-time)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
NSLog(@"%@",subTotal);
```

is wrong: You want to print a float value, not an object. Use `%f` instead.